# Detect Magic as Ritual casting to find magic item?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, duration

I am new as DM running my fourth session playing D&D 5e.
I have five experienced players who sometimes use logic that seems suspicious.

One of my players is a wizard. They cast [Detect Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic) as a ritual to search for magical items, barriers, or a person who has magic.

I don't have a problem with them walking while casting detect magic as a ritual, but the problem is about the size of the area.

The party thinks they can scan the area during their ritual while walking with a 30 feet radius while casting.

So in 10 minutes, the wizard can scan the area using detect magic.

Is that possible? It feels broken on some level.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Your players misunderstand how rituals work.

Casting a ritual adds a time cost of ten additional minutes to the casting time. So casting [Detect Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic) this way takes one action and ten minutes before they gain the benefit of the effect.

[Detect Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic) has a regular duration of ten minutes, but your players need to cast the spell first before they can use it - they can either do so by using a spell slot or spending the additional time cost of the ritual. [Rituals](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Rituals):

> Certain spells have a special tag: ritual. Such a spell can be cast
> following the normal rules for spellcasting, or the spell can be cast
> as a ritual. The ritual version of a spell takes 10 minutes longer to
> cast than normal. It also doesn't expend a spell slot, which means the
> ritual version of a spell can't be cast at a higher level.

For more information read the section about [Casting Time](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingTime).

Also note that [Detect Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic) is a spell that requires [concentration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Concentration), so the wizard needs to maintain concentration while scouting out the area.

> Some spells require you to maintain concentration in order to keep
> their magic active. If you lose concentration, such a spell ends.
> [...]
>
> Normal activity, such as moving and attacking, doesn't interfere with
> concentration. The following factors can break concentration:
>
> - **Casting another spell that requires concentration.** You lose
>   concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires
>   concentration. You can't concentrate on two spells at once.
> - **Taking damage.** Whenever you take damage while you are concentrating on a
>   spell, you must make a Constitution saving throw to maintain your
>   concentration. The DC equals 10 or half the damage you take, whichever
>   number is higher. If you take damage from multiple sources, such as an
>   arrow and a dragon's breath, you make a separate saving throw for each
>   source of damage.
> - **Being incapacitated or killed.** You loseconcentration on a spell if you are
>   incapacitated or if you die. [...]

Also note that the penetrative magic detection of [Detect Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic) is restricted by materials:

> The spell can penetrate most barriers, but it is blocked by 1 foot of
> stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood
> or dirt.

So while the way the players used [Detect Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic) to scan an area within 10 minutes with a 30 feet radius is correct, they disregarded the cost to ritual casting - and there are additional things that you have to consider when they use [Detect Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic) like materials blocking off vision, concentration, and time, or spell slot cost - all of which are limited resources in dangerous situations.

Comment: So basically what players did was a valid use of Detect Magic, except that they needed 10 minutes more to perform the ritual before gaining the spell effect. I think this is an important point to add.